# Regex can't getting the blank spaces and I can't split the string correctly?

Tags: python, regex

I'm creating a Regex in Python where I need to find a blank spaces in a string

Example

```
000#0123456789#ASimpleName#123456 000#987654321#OtherSimpleName#8765432
000#0123456789#ASimpleName#EUA 000#987654321#OtherSimpleName#8765432
```

In this case, if I use `re.split('\s'`) I solve my problem, but I can find this

```
000#0123456789#A simple Name#123456 000#987654321#Other Simple Name#8765432
000#0123456789#ASimpleName#EUA 000#987654321#OtherSimpleName#8765432
```

I've tried to use this expression `[\d|\w]\s\d`, but the Regex get `6 0` and `A 0`, but I need only the blank space.

Comment: Try `\s+(?=000#)` or `\s+(?=\d{3}#)`

Comment: Thank you man, you saved me!

Comment: So, I would like to understand your Regex. In this case, how can I read the ?= expression? I know using parentheses after plus signal, you find the string, but ignore them, right?

Comment: These are lookarounds, lookaheads, that are non-consuming, i.e. do not add the matched text to the whole matched value and do not move the regex index, the regex index always remains where it was before matching the lookaround pattern.

Comment: Wait. Maybe I'm not understanding something. Based on the question why not just literally find "space" via `([\ ]+)`? I mean lookarounds are better practice, but if your requirement fits the above, `([\ ]+)` works without any complexity. `([\ ]+)` also avoids capturing '\n' so you don't need numbers as qualifiers.

Comment: @FailSafe If you mention "complexity" then you should suggest `" +"`. However, it won't help because the name may contain spaces, see `Other Simple Name`

Comment: Love it. When I read his post it says, **`"but I can find this"`** instead of **`can't`**.  I see that there was a little bit of a language barrier here. No problem.

Comment: But on the subject of complexity vs. anti-complexity, I usually design for scalability. So if there are other, even alternating, patterns he might want to add to the capture he can add them between the brackets, and I designate a capture group to assure that if conditions change and he wants to add a separate capture group, the one designated will still be captured, not ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the following regex with `re.split`:

```
\s+(?=000#)
```

Or, if there may be any 3 digits:

```
\s+(?=\d{3}#)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8tyHRG/1) and the https://jex.im/regulex diagrams:

[image]

**Details**

- `\s+` - matches and consumes 1 or more whitespace chars
- `(?=\d{3}#)` - makes sure that, immediately to the right of the current location, there are 3 digits followed with `#`. `(?=000#)` returns true only if the three digits are zeros. `#` may not be necessary here, but that depends on the actual data and requirements.